# Usage of under the aegis

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I really want to use the phrase 'under the aegis' in a small paragraph but want to be grammatically correct. I am planning to write "thankful to xxxx for taking me under their aegis" or "under the aegis of whom I grew....".

Are any or both of these phrases correct? I can't find usage of the word "aegis" in this way elsewhere.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you looked it up? Macmillan says “under the protection or authority of a particular group, government, or person,” and given the origin, there’s a strong connotation of “shield” in this word.

Comment: "Taking me under their aegis" sounds wrong to me even though I understand what you mean by it. *Aegis* is not a particularly common word, and I would suggest using an uncommon word in a way that it is not normally used may make it seem like you don't know quite what it means.